# Pivot from row to column - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table:

Table1

```
row_id     var        var_val
1          Test 1      123
1          Test 2      456
1          Test 3      789
1          Test 4      1234
2          Test 1      665t
2          Test 2      dsfs
2          Test 3      df
2          Test 4      sfd
3          Test 1      sfs
3          Test 2      sf
3          Test 3      sdfs
3          Test 4      sfsd
```

Here is the output:

Table2

```
row_id      var1        var2
1           123         456
2           665t        dsfs
3           sfs         sf
```

- For var1 - get value where var = "Test 1"
- For var2 - get value where var = "Test 2"

Is there a way to use pivot or some way of extracting the variable for each row_id from the table1 as per above?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: table2 is the output

Comment: What does column var1 and var2 contains? how it is being calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation or a `join`:

```
select t11.row_id, t11.var, t12.var
from table1 t11 join
     table1 t12
     on t11.row_id = t12.row_id and
        t11.var = 'Test 1' and
        t12.var = 'Test 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use pivot...?

Sure:

```
select * 
  from table1
  pivot (max(var_val) for var in ('Test 1' var1, 'Test 2' var2))
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ee9d2ff737cdc98f48215d4d75713649)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `correlated subqueries` and `row_number()` window analytic function together

```
with table1(row_id, var, var_val) as
(
 select 1,'Test 1','123'  from dual union all
 select 1,'Test 2','456'  from dual union all
 select 1,'Test 3','789'  from dual union all
 select 1,'Test 4','1234' from dual union all
 select 2,'Test 1','665t' from dual union all
 select 2,'Test 2','dsfs' from dual union all
 select 2,'Test 3','df'   from dual union all
 select 2,'Test 4','sfd'  from dual union all
 select 3,'Test 1','sfs'  from dual union all
 select 3,'Test 2','sf'   from dual union all
 select 3,'Test 3','sdfs' from dual union all
 select 3,'Test 4','sfsd' from dual
), t2 as
(
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by var order by row_id) as rn
  from table1 t
)
select distinct row_id,
                (select var_val
                   from table1 t2
                  where t2.var = 'Test 1'
                    and t2.row_id = rn) as var1,
                (select var_val
                   from table1 t2
                  where t2.var = 'Test 2'
                    and t2.row_id = rn) as var2
  from t2
 order by row_id

 ROW_ID VAR1    VAR2
 ------ ----    ----
 1      123     456
 2      665t    dsfs
 3      sfs     sf
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/LPCMCN32253)</kbd>